# .NET (web) How to execute some code after all events are handled?

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have this .NET web app that draws a table in Page_Load.

Then after that it handles the events, which should change the table drawn in Page_Load.
This is very inefficient.

Is there a way to execute the code (which draws the table) after it finishes handling all events? (instead of doing it in Page_Load)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to handle an event that occurs after the control events, but before the page is rendered, such as [LoadComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcomplete.aspx) or [PreRender](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.prerender.aspx).

Check out the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the OnPreRender event in the page lifecycle.

-Oisin

Answer (score 0):

You could also put the code in a Timer tick event with an interval of 1, which will fire after all the events.